# Run Sonarqube stage with jdk 11 docker image

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube, java-11, docker-image

I am currently building a project that uses JDK 8. However, during the execution of the SonarQube stage, I encountered an issue related to logs indicating that one of the plugins installed in my SonarQube service is not compatible with the JDK version used for project building.

Now, I am trying to find a solution to run the SonarQube stage with JDK version 11. Here is the current configuration of the stage:

```
stage('Sonar') {
    environment {
        SCANNER_HOME= tool 'sonarscanner'
    }
    agent {
        docker {
            label 'sonar'
            image "artifact.me.com/docker/jdk/jdk-11:latest"
            args "-itd -v ${SCANNER_HOME}:/var/sonarScanner --privileged=true"
        }
    }
    steps {
        withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQube') {
            withVault([configuration: configuration, vaultSecrets: secrets]) {
                sh "/var/sonarScanner/bin/sonar-scanner -D ..."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, the build stucks when this stage is reached, and here is the error message displayed in the console:

```
15:13:06  Login Succeeded
15:13:06  [Pipeline] {
15:13:06  [Pipeline] isUnix
15:13:07  [Pipeline] withEnv
15:13:07  [Pipeline] {
15:13:07  [Pipeline] sh
15:18:14  process apparently never started in /data/jenkins/workspace/sonar-test@2@tmp/durable-928c6c08
15:18:14  (running Jenkins temporarily with -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true might make the problem clearer)
```

Answer (score 0):

### A possible solution/workaround is to use sonar-scanner-cli jar file

**Step 1:** 
Download s[onar-scanner jar fil](https://artifact.me.com/artifactory/maven-central/org/sonarsource/scanner/cli/sonar-scanner-cli/5.0.1.3006/sonar-scanner-cli-5.0.1.3006.jar)e using from maven-central by use of artifactory proxy.

**Step 2:**

Run sonar-scanner using java.

`sh "java -jar ./sonar-scanner -D..."`

Comment: Same problem
```
15:29:20  INFO: SonarScanner 4.8.0.2856
15:29:20  INFO: Java 1.8.0_372 Temurin (64-bit)
15:29:22  WARN: SonarScanner will require Java 11 to run, starting in SonarQube 9.x
15:29:27  INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------15:29:27  INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
15:29:27  ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
15:29:27  java.lang.IllegalStateException: The plugin [cxx] does not support Java 1.8.0_372
```